# What is the past form of the structure "used to"?

Tags: grammar, synonyms, tenses

We generally change the tense of the verb and shift back when reporting something (unless it's still true, has just been said, or is a scientific fact). For example, "I was sitting in the car" changes to "She said she had been sitting in the car". When backshifting, how should we change "used to" in the indirect speech?

For example, when we are reporting the sentence

"I used to play volleyball when I was a kid"

it changes to an indirect speech and becomes

"She told me she ____________ play volleyball when she was a kid"

a) used to
b) had used to (odd, I think)
c) ?

Is "used to" similar to other modal verbs such as "should" and "would" with which we don't do the backshift in the reported speech?

Comment: What is wrong with "She said she *was* sitting in the car"? You would need "had been" only with two activities, to set one before the other: She said she had been sitting in the car when the rain began.

Comment: 'used to play' according to conventional grammar changes to 'used to have played...'.   He said, "I used to visit her." He said that he used to have visited her.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore, I know; that is the reason I mentioned 'conventional grammar'. Conventional styles used would do -> would have done; could do -> could have done; similarly used to do -> used to have done...